# Object oriented design PHP: many if-elseif's that check the same condition but define different behaviour in classes

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

I use Zend Framework (the MVC), but the question is generic. In my system, I have several layers of abstraction: mappers, services (or repositories), view scripts, the objects. The problem is that depending on the type of objects, the factories for mappers, services, and so on have to instantiate specific mappers, services, etc. So in the factories, I use the same `if` condition but outputting different object, for example:

```
if ('type1' == $objectType) {
    $mapper = new DbMapperForObjectType1();
} elseif ('type2' == $objectType) {
    $mapper = new DbMapperForObjectType2();
} 
// etc.
return $mapper;
```

The same goes for services and other things.

I wonder if there's a design pattern or solution to put these `if`'s for different things into one place to avoid repeating them in different factories.

Comment: Why can't you create a single factory, encapsulate it as a module, and include it in everyfile that needs to instantiate a db mapper object?

Comment: this would be the solution if i had only mappers, but i have other things, like services, view scripts and so on that are instantiated with the same `if-elseif` conditions that i described above. it's just the content of the `if-elseif`'s changes a bit. you saw for the mappers, for the services that would be `if ('type1' == $objectType) {$service = new ServiceForObjectType1}` etc. i was wondering if i could place everything in one place somehow...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)  A design like the one you are suggesting, arguably, violates the single responsibility principle.  The class is responsible for instantiating vastly different objects.  Additionally, I would question the design, and explore alternative ways to try and improve it, instead of trying to find a way to reuse the current design as-is.

Comment: after thinking about this, you're 100% right. i'll rethink the concept. thanks!